# How to change a number to text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i currently have something which rolls onto a number but i'd like to change it so instead of displaying the number it rolled on, it displays the name which the number is apart of. A snippet of what i have is below:

```
function spin(m) {
    var x = m.roll;
    play_sound("roll");
    var order = [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8];
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if (x == order[i]) {
            index = i;
            break
        }
    }
    var max = 32;
    var min = -32;
    var w = Math.floor(m.wobble * (max - min + 1) + min);
    var dist = index * 70 + 36 + w;
    dist += 1050 * 5;
    animStart = new Date().getTime();
    vi = getVi(dist);
    tf = getTf(vi);
    isMoving = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        finishRoll(m, tf)
    }, tf);
    render()
}
```

As you can see I have 1, 14, 2, 13 etc.
I would like it so if it rolls onto 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7 it shows 'Group1' instead of the number it has landed on.
The same goes with 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9 and 8 except i'd like it to show 'Group2' instead of the number it has landed on.
Now for 0, i'd like it so it shows 'Green' instead of 0 when it lands on it.
These are the main snippets in the file.
1.

```
function cd(ms, cb) {
    $("#counter").finish().css("width", "100%");
    $("#counter").animate({
        width: "0%"
    }, {
        "duration": ms * 1000,
        "easing": "linear",
        progress: function(a, p, r) {
            var c = (r / 1000).toFixed(2);
            $BANNER.html("Rolling in " + c + "...");
        },
        complete: cb
    });
}
```

2.

```
function finishRoll(m, tf) {
    $BANNER.html("Rolled number " + m.roll + "!");
    addHist(m.roll, m.rollid);
    play_sound("finish");
    for (var i = 0; i < m.nets.length; i++) {
        $("#panel" + m.nets[i].lower + "-" + m.nets[i].upper).find(".total").countTo(m.nets[i].swon > 0 ? m.nets[i].swon : -m.nets[i].samount, {
            "color": true,
            "keep": true
        });
    }
    var cats = [
        [0, 0],
        [1, 7],
        [8, 14]
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        var $mytotal = $("#panel" + cats[i][0] + "-" + cats[i][1]).find(".mytotal");
        if (m.roll >= cats[i][0] && m.roll <= cats[i][1]) {
            $mytotal.countTo(m.won, {
                "color": true,
                "keep": true
            });
        } else {
            var curr = parseFloat($mytotal.html());
            if ($("#settings_dongers").is(":checked")) {
                curr *= 1000;
            }
            $mytotal.countTo(-curr, {
                "color": true,
                "keep": true
            });
        }
    }
    if (m.balance != null) {
        $("#balance").countTo(m.balance, {
            "color": true
        });
        checkplus(m.balance);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        cd(m.count);
        $(".total,.mytotal").removeClass("text-success text-danger").html(0);
        $(".betlist li").remove();
        snapRender();
        $(".betButton").prop("disabled", false);
        showbets = true;
    }, m.wait * 1000 - tf);
}
```

3.

```
function snapRender(x, wobble) {
    CASEW = $("#case").width();
    if (isMoving) return;
    else if (typeof x === 'undefined') view(snapX);
    else {
        var order = [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8];
        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
            if (x == order[i]) {
                index = i;
                break
            }
        }
        var max = 32;
        var min = -32;
        var w = Math.floor(wobble * (max - min + 1) + min);
        var dist = index * 70 + 36 + w;
        dist += 1050 * 5;
        snapX = dist;
        view(snapX)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
// assumes n is always a number between 0 and 14 (inclusive)
function numberToName(n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return "Green";
    } else if (n < 8) {
        return "Group1";
    } else {
        return "Group2";
    }
}
```

Just call this with the chosen number and then use the returned text however you want.

Comment: Where would i put that exactly? and would I have to switch anything around for it to display the returned text as at the moment it still displays the number.

Comment: Wherever you're displaying the number, call this function and display the result instead. (I don't know where in your code you actually display the number right now. Maybe somewhere in `render` or `view`? I think it's in part of the code you didn't share, unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: The number is displayed in snippet 2 where it says     `$BANNER.html("Rolled number " + m.roll + "!");` Just instead of the number where m.roll is i want Group1, Green or Group2.

Comment: So replace `m.roll` with `numberToName(m.roll)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!